# How to sitecore save data into Oracle?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to build a solution that can be save data from Sitecore into oracle database but after search on google, I haven't idea to do this. Everyone have can help me ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have the CMS run from Oracle (which is not supported as @Marek answered) or save some specific data to custom Oracle tables?

Comment: @jammykam, I only want to save some data into an oracle table. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to save something custom...say form information into an Oracle table, then it would be normal C# coding as usual.

1) You will need a connection string in your connectionstrings.config file or web.config depending on if you isolated your connection strings to an external file or not:

```
<add name="oracle_registration" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=99.999.999.999)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=WEBDEV))); User Id=userid; Password=userpwd" />
```

2) Make sure you have the Oracle client DLL and referenced in your project:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

3) Example of simple Oracle connection and query execution:

```
private OracleConnection _connection;
if (null == _connection)
{
  _connection = new OracleConnection(this.ConnectionString);
  _connection.Open();
}    

using (OracleCommand cfc = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cfc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (FORM_NUMBER, FORM_DATA) VALUES (:1, :2)";

            cfc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("paramFormNumber", OracleDbType.Int64, "Number", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cfc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("paramFormData", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "Data", ParameterDirection.Input));

            cfc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's what I need. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore XP 8 does **NOT** support Oracle by default.

Oracle is supported by older Sitecore versions only.

See [Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164) for more details.

Still there is an asterisk note saying:

> Please contact us at **oraclesupport@sitecore.net** if you require Oracle support for Sitecore 7.5 or later.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.